# no puedo pasar una variable por echo

Tags: php

espero puedan echarme una mano, tengo el siguiente problema estoy haciendo una tabla dinámica y ya sale bien con el siguiente código:

```
while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $fila['num_ANI'];
            $salida.= "<tr>
                            <td>".$fila['num_ANI']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['serie']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['fecha_ingreso']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['modelo']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['stado']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
                            <td>".$fila['nombre_vendedor']."</td>
                            <td>"."<a href='modificaANI.php?id=6 >
                            '<span ><i class='fa-solid fa-pen-to-square text-info'></i>
                            </span>'</a>"."</td>
                            
                        </tr>";
        } 
        $salida.="</tbody></table>";                
    } else{
        $salida.= "No hay datos :(";
    }
    echo $salida;
    $mysqli->close();y tengo algo como la imagen
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el problema esd que paso un id= 6 para editar el registro, pero yo necesito pasar el id dinamico y cuando hago esta linea de codigo:

```
   while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
               echo $fila['num_ANI'];
               $salida.= "<tr>
                               <td>".$fila['num_ANI']."</td>
                               <td>".$fila['serie']."</td>
                               <td>".$fila['fecha_ingreso']."</td>
                               <td>".$fila['modelo']."</td>
                               <td>".$fila['stado']."</td>
                               <td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>
                               <td>".$fila['nombre_vendedor']."</td>
                               <td>"."<a href='modificaANI.php?id="echo $fila['num_ANI'];" >
                               '<span ><i class='fa-solid fa-pen-to-square text-info'></i>
                               </span>'</a>"."</td>
                               
                           </tr>";
           } 
           $salida.="</tbody></table>";                
       } else{
           $salida.= "No hay datos :(";
       }
       echo $salida;
       $mysqli->close();
   ?>
```

me marca el sigueinte error;

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "echo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\App\buscarANI.php on line 41

no se como pasar el valor con el echo

Comment: por que no simplemente concatenas el valor tal cual lo estas haciendo con los otros valores?

Comment: el echo se usan para mostrar cadenas de caracteres por pantalla como una impresion de datos, no son para pasar datos: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php

Answer (score 1):

`echo` es una salida de php, no sirve para concatenar dentro de un tipo de datos.
Observa que esa cadena la vas a imprimir más abajo con otro echo, `echo $salida;`.
Entonces la línea en cuestión debe quedar:

```
<td>"."<a href='modificaANI.php?id=".$fila['num_ANI']."'>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, jalo al 100 con esta concatenación.

Comment: Un código más sencillo, que evitaría concatenación, sería poner todo dentro de comillas dobles y escapar las comillas dobles que sean parte del contenido, algo así: **`"<td><a href=\"modificaANI.php?id=$fila[num_ANI]\"></td>";`**